# Stanford CORENLP Master Keep Crashing (NullPointerException)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server, corenlp-server

I downloaded the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP with the larger english model from [this link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar)

Placing the model downloaded in the same project folder, i am using "ant" / "ant jar" to build the project.

I then load the server using this command on windows:

```
java -d64 -mx20g -classpath "*;lib\*;liblocal\*;libsrc\*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 500000
```

Loading the result page from http://localhost:9000 , the server crashes when using filters such as relations, coreference.

I get the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The log from server:

Some annotation fail such as:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MentionAnnotator - Error with building coref mention annotator!
```

And the main problem / exception:

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:497)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MentionAnnotator.annotate(MentionAnnotator.java:100)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:75)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:606)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.lambda$handle$344(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:479)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Any help on what could be causing this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you feeding to the library? I used to run coreNLP library in IntelliJ and Netbeans and I had an issue where if I fed a blank space (either one or more spaces, a tab or an empty blank line) I would get a null pointer exception. I had to check every sentence so they wouldn't be blank when feeding it to the coreNLP library. (I was storing each sentence as a String in a Array, so if I stored a blank string in the array and passed it to the CoreNLP library it would crash). I don't know if its your case but hope this helps.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for trying to help. I ended up using the stable version on the website and dropping few features. It was consuming lots of time so i dropped it.

Comment: Nice, I am glad you were able to figure it out. Yes it is much easier to use the website. Just be sure not to use it for large volumes of request since it is a public API. In case you need to process large volumes of text you should use CoreNLP as a dedicated server.